# Initial size for the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

You can set the initial size for an ArrayList by doing

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
```

However, you can't do

```
arr.add(5, 10);
```

because it causes an out of bounds exception.

What is the use of setting an initial size if you can't access the space you allocated?

The add function is defined as `add(int index, Object element)` so I am not adding to index 10.

Comment: Actually, its not obvious from the docs that a list needs to have at least *n* items added before you can `set/add` item *n-1*.

Comment: Perception: I don't know if it is obvious, but it is specified. One has to read JavaDoc carefully.Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).

Comment: Hm, the constructor says "Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.", taking the notion of an empty list, there cant be an index 5. But i agree that this might not be visible at first glance...

Comment: I think it's also fair to say that if you initialize an array to a specific value, you're going to assume indices lower than that value are available—and this is an `ArrayList`.  I, personally, would like a method that would allow me to set a size such that I could put things in at specific indices.  This method seems notably absent.

Comment: What numbskull designed the collections this way?! This forces redundant work for parallel instantiation of a structure with variable-length elements (i.e. ArrayList<String[]> where each array can have a different length). If the memory is already allocated so the list doesn't need reallocation after adding N elements, those indices should be directly accessible from the start. Has no one at Oracle learned this pattern after C/C++, C#, Objective C, and Swift?!

Comment: @AndrewWyld `java.util.Vector` has a `setSize(int)` method, but that class is unfortunately synchronized and thus slower than `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 508, accepted):

You're confusing the size of the array list with its capacity:

- the **size** is the number of elements in the list;
- the **capacity** is how many elements the list can potentially accommodate without reallocating its internal structures.

When you call `new ArrayList<Integer>(10)`, you are setting the list's initial *capacity*, not its size. In other words, when constructed in this manner, the array list starts its life empty.

One way to add ten elements to the array list is by using a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.add(0);
}
```

Having done this, you can now modify elements at indices 0..9.

Comment: +1: A shorter loop is `while(arr.size() < 10) arr.add(0);` It can be useful to say, the size needs to be at least `10`. e.g. so you can use `arr.set(9, n);`

Comment: +1: Great response, I would give +10 if I could.  It is not immediately obvious from the api why you cannot set BOTH the initial size and the initial capacity in a single constructor call.  You sort of have to read through the api and say "Oh, I guess ArrayList does not have a method or constructor to do that"

Comment: @PeterLawrey Your code might be shorter, but contains two method calls per loop iteration, rather than just one.

Comment: @neuralmer I would expect size() and add() to be inlined so no actual method call occurs at runtime.

Answer (score 164):

If you want a list with a predefined size you can also use:

```
List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]);
```

Comment: Slight disadvantage here, the resulting `List` is full of nulls.  With Guava we can do `Ints.asList(new int[10])` which will initialize our list with `0`s.  Clean pattern though, thanks for the example.

Comment: The questions talks about ArrayList<E>. You are using List<E>. No one has observed this??? Moreover, they have upvoted this *irrelevant* answer! I don't downvote your answer because I never do. Simply ... Godssake!

Comment: @Apostolos `ArrayList` is an implementation of the `List` interface and `Arrays.asList` returns an `ArrayList`. I suggest you look up polymorphism.

Comment: This returns a List with a fixed size though. Trying to add more elements throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: We could wrap it with the ArrayList constructor to get an ArrayList: `ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]));`

Comment: @dimo414, sometimes null is better than adding a 3rd party library dependency.

Comment: If you intend to add even more elements to the list (beyond the initial size), you could use:
```List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]));```

Comment: @LiamPotter The `Arrays.asList` method does *not* return a `java.util.ArrayList`. It returns a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, an inner class of `Arrays`. Confusingly named.

Answer (score 69):

if you want to use Collections.fill(list, obj); in order to fill the list with a repeated object alternatively you can use

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, 0));
```

the line copies 10 times 0 in to your ArrayList

Answer (score 24):

**Capacity** of an `ArrayList` isn't the same as its **size**. **Size** is equal to the number of elements contained in the `ArrayList` (and any other `List` implementation).

The **capacity** is just the length of the underlying array which is used to internaly store the elements of the `ArrayList`, and is always greater or equal to the **size** of the list.

When calling `set(index, element)` on the list, the `index` relates to the actual number of the list elements (=size) (which is zero in your code, therefore the `AIOOBE` is thrown), not to the array length (=capacity) (which is an implementation detail specific to the `ArrayList`).

The `set` method is common to all `List` implementations, such as `LinkedList`, which isn't actually implemented by an array, but as a linked chain of entries.

**Edit**: You actually use the `add(index, element)` method, not `set(index, element)`, but the principle is the same here.

Answer (score 10):

10 is the initial capacity of the AL, not the size (which is 0). You should mention the initial capacity to some high value when you are going to have a lots of elements, because it avoids the overhead of expanding the capacity as you keep adding elements.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add the elements with index, you could instead use an array.

```
    String [] test = new String[length];
    test[0] = "add";
```

Comment: OP wanted to use a List initially... not an array.

Answer (score 7):

This might help someone -

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]));
```

Answer (score 7):

Being late to this, but after **Java 8**, I personally find this following approach with the `Stream` API more concise and can be an alternative to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896824/10734272).

For example,

`Arrays.stream(new int[size]).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

where `size` is the desired `List` size and without [the disadvantage mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist/36518805#comment39907288_23586315), all elements in the `List` are initialized as `0`.

(I did a quick search and did not see `stream` in any answers posted - feel free to let me know if this answer is redundant and I can remove it)

Comment: can I populate it on the go too? I have a list of objects I got from database and I need that list to be of fixed size too

Answer (score 6):

I guess an exact answer to your question would be:

Setting an intial size on an ArrayList reduces the nr. of times internal memory re-allocation has to occur.
The list is backed by an array. If you specify i.e. initial capacity 0, already at the first insertion of an element the internal array would have to be resized.
If you have an approximate idea of how many elements your list would hold, setting the initial capacity would reduce the nr. of memory re-allocations happening while you use the list.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with the similar issue, and just knowing the arrayList is a resizable-array implementation of the List interface, I also expect you can add element to any point, but at least have the option to define the initial size. 
Anyway, you can create an array first and convert that to a list like:

```
  int index = 5;
  int size = 10;

  Integer[] array = new Integer[size];
  array[index] = value;
  ...
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

or

```
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[size]);
  list.set(index, value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now there are no elements in your list so you cannot add to index 5 of the list when it does not exist. You are confusing the capacity of the list with its current size.

Just call:

```
arr.add(10)
```

to add the Integer to your ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

My two cents on `Stream`. I think it's better to use

```
IntStream.generate(i -> MyClass.contruct())
         .limit(INT_SIZE)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with the flexibility to put any initial values.

Answer (score 1):

Although your arraylist has a capacity of 10, the real list has no elements here. The add method is used to insert a element to the real list. Since it has no elements, you can't insert an element to the index of 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add 10 items to your `ArrayList` you may try that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    arr.add(i);
```

If you have already declare an array size variable you would use the variable `size` instead of number '10'

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(10);

```
//  myList.add(3, "DDD");
//  myList.add(9, "III");
    myList.add(0, "AAA");
    myList.add(1, "BBB");

    for(String item:myList){
        System.out.println("inside list : "+item);
    }
```

/*Declare the initial capasity of arraylist is nothing but saving shifting time in internally; when we add the element internally it check the capasity to increase the capasity, you could add the element at 0 index initially then 1 and so on. */

Answer (score 0):

contrib..

```
List <Destination\> destinations = Collections.nCopies(source.size(), Destination.class.newInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument we pass say **N** to constructor is the capacity of memory reserved for **N** elements, not the size of the array list i.e the no of elements, for more info can refer to [official docs: ArrayList constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#constructor.summary).

But still what you was to achieve can be easily done with little changes in the code by assigning **N** elements with some default value initially and the instead of using `add()` use `set()` method to update the values

```java
import java.util.*;

class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int DEFAULT_INT_VALUE = 0;

    // set first 10 elements with default value 0
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, DEFAULT_INT_VALUE));

    // why to use set(5, 10) instead of add(5, 10)..? simply because add() will insert new element at index 5, which here actually we just to modify the 5 index element in array list
    arr.set(5, 10);

    // output: arr= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    System.out.println("arr= " + arr.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is this:

```
EvictingQueue<Integer> ignitionOnOdometer = EvictingQueue.create(size);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).