# ArrayList Out of Bound exception

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> Array=new ArrayList<>(5);
Array.add("Ten");
Array.add("Twenty");
Array.add(4,"Fifty");
Array.add("Thirty");
Array.add("Fourty");
System.out.println(Array);
```

I got the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception when I run this code. Can anyone explain the reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please paste original code

Comment: you cannot add on a position that is not still available in the list. At the time adding at `4` there is no `4th` position. Initializing the list with `5` is the capacity and not the size.

Comment: Can you specify what is your end goal?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is caused by your misunderstanding of the first argument to the `ArrayList` constructor. It is not the initial *size* you are providing, but the *capacity*.

The `ArrayList` class works with both a size and capacity. The size is the actual number of added elements within the list. The capacity, however, is the size of the internal array of `ArrayList` where the actual elements are stored. If enough elements are added, the capacity is increased by copying all elements of the current internal array to a new array with double the size of the current one. This is done because otherwise you have to expand the internal array *each time an element is added*. That would seriously impact performance.

The single-argument constructor accepts the *initial capacity*, and not the size. It's common not to specify the capacity, because the capacity is initialized to a sensible default. This constructor, however, exists mainly for performance reasons: if it is known that the number of elements will become very large, one could set the capacity through that constructor, so the `ArrayList` does not have to resize a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add "Fifty" at index 4, which is not available because the size of ArrayList is 2 at that point of execution.

**Array.add(4,"Fifty");**  Adding "Fifty" at index 4

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)), it clearly mentions that:

> Throws:
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

At the point of execution, your list size will be 2 and 4 > size i.e 2. Hence, this exception will be thrown.

You can check out the same discussion in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist) as well.

Comment: There are some more comments about this topic on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

From the `void java.util.ArrayList.add(int index, Object element)` method declaration :

```
Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range(index < 0 || index > size())
```

So you cant add to index number 4 because there is not one at the time the method is called

Answer (score 0):

Your code declares the *capacity* of your ArrayList, not its actual *size*. So you can add elements, but adding to position 4 fails because that position doesn't yet exist.

You can check that by looking at the size of your array as you add elements:

```
System.out.println(array.size());
```

Adding a value increases your array's size by 1. But if your array's size is only 2, you'll get an error if you try adding a value to position 4.

Depending on your end goal, you could add a couple blank values in order to initialize those positions, then add to position 4:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(5);
```

Then you can do your adds:

```
array.add("Ten");
array.add("Twenty");
array.add("");
array.add("");
array.add(4,"Fifty");
array.add("Thirty");
array.add("Fourty");
System.out.println(array);
```