# Java ArrayList is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException. Why?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my current progress on a project. I am trying to implement this ArrayList stuff but file continues to trow the same exception.

```
import java.util.*;

   public class Numerican{

      public static void main( String [] args ){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);

        int count = input.nextInt() * 2;

        while (count > 0){
           array.add( 0 );
           count = count - 1;
           array.add(count, 2);
        }

        array.add(2, input.nextInt());
        System.out.println(array.get(2));

      }
   }
```

It was my understanding that `= new ArrayList<Integer>(10);` would set the array size to 10. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: I suppose problem is with this line `array.add(count, 2);` . Is it?

Comment: @codeMan That's my guess, too, after a closer look.

Comment: I dont think so. I tried removing the while loop and it still gave me the same exception.

Comment: @Alexander array.add(2, input.nextInt()); here is the possible exception...  when count is 1. you are accessing more than the size of the list which is 2.

Comment: @Alexander Yes the exception is at `array.add(count, 2);`  particular point. (If you see my answer). If you insert `input > 5` then count becomes more than 10, and `array.add(count, 2);` means `add(index, element)`

Comment: See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908037/arraylist-initial-capacity-and-indexoutofboundsexception?lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
= new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
```

This line initializes the CAPACITY to 10, meaning the memory is allocated in the backend, but as far as you are concerned, the array is still empty.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) -

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
    Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
```

This is why the calls to `add` might fail, if you try to add beyond the size of the `ArrayList`.

p.s. remember that `add` function takes index first and then element, when using the 2 parameter variant.

Edit:

ArrayList has 2 different member variables, **size** and **capacity**. Capacity is how much memory is allocated, size is how many elements are inserted by programmer.

Here, Capacity = 10, Size = 0;

Comment: I guess I still don't understand why the while loop would not add to the array. Even when the count is less than 10 (array size)

Comment: @Alexander you need to understand how ArrayList works. It has 2 members, size and capacity. Capacity is how much memory is allocated, size is how many elements are inserted by programmer

Comment: Here the array CAPACITY is 10, and as javadoc reveals, initial size is 0

Comment: So, can you shed some light on a possible solution?

Comment: @Alexander is it not possible to add without specific index? If not you can write a loop that will add 10 elements before this code.

Comment: By specific index you mean `array.add(count, 2);`?

Comment: @Alexander yes that is what I mean

Comment: Yeah, I guess that works. Major sleep deprivation avoided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size()) IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown. 
So i think you are accessing index > size() of the list.

size() ===> Returns the number of elements in this list.

array.add(2, input.nextInt()); here is the possible exception when your list size is 1...

Comment: @asifsid88 I have metioned the exact line and the cause of the issue too... what else you want ??

Comment: @asifsid88 I didn't get your point; without that while loop also he is able to see the exception rit ??

Answer (score 0):

According to [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29):

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Note that the ArrayList is *empty* (i.e. does not contain any items). The value indicates the *capacity* of the ArrayList which is the number of elements which can be added before more memory must be allocated.

On the other hand, calling `add()` actually adds an item to the ArrayList. In your example, `array.add( 0 );` adds a `0` at the end of the list and `array.add(count, 2);` adds a `2` at index `count`. I suspect the problem is that `count` is not a valid index in your `ArrayList`. You should check what its value is by inserting an SOP or using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Hey seems like your  Problem is because of the line

```
array.add(count, 2);
```

adds a 2 at index count

For example your input size is 5 then `array.add(9,2);` the array size is only 1 by that time  as capacity and size are two different parameters for a ArrayList. So you can use a for loop instead of while to insert your values

```
for(int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
array.add(i,2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`count maybe >= 10`, maybe souce code can answer you question:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);

    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
                     size - index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    size++;
}
```

rangeCheckForAdd():

```
/**
 * A version of rangeCheck used by add and addAll.
 */
private void rangeCheckForAdd(int index) {
    if (index > size || index < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of ArrayList, you need to add items to the list in a sequential index.
i.e.  You cannot add an item to the 7th index position if 1 to 6 have not been filled in.

ArrayList.add(indexPosition, element);

If you add elements to the list, starting at indexPosition 0, and increasing the indexPosition by 1 each time, it should work.

Ex.

`int i = 0;

(while i < 10){

    array.add(i, numberToAdd); 

i++; 
}`