# ArrayList data structure index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array list with an initial size of `10` using this code.

```
List<EWSMessage> messages = new ArrayList<EWSMessage>(10);
List<EWSMessage> newMessages =  new ArrayList<EWSMessage>(startMessages.size() - 10);

for (int i = 0, count = startMessages.size(); i < count; i++) {
  if (i < 10) {
    messages.set(i, startMessages.get(i));
  } else {
    newMessages.set(i - 10,startMessages.get(i));
  }
}
```

My issue is I need to fill the array list before I can set the values in the for loop. I just don't understand how to do this. Also `startMessages` is declared in the method as a `List<EWSMessages>`.

Comment: You now that an array list like an other list in java has no limit? Ok the heap size ;) But thats fair away from 10. Also when you define the arraylist with capacity of 10, it can grow aboth it! Don't mix ArrayList with Arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayList initial capacity and IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908037/arraylist-initial-capacity-and-indexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 2):

This line creates a list with an initial *capacity* of 10 -- but size zero.

```
List<EWSMessage> messages = new ArrayList<EWSMessage>(10);
```

Providing the initial capacity is optional. The list will grow as you add elements to it.

An easy way to add elements is with the [add() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-):

```
List<EWSMessage> messages = new ArrayList<EWSMessage>();
List<EWSMessage> newMessages =  new ArrayList<EWSMessage>();

for (int i = 0, count = startMessages.size(); i < count; i++) {
    if (i < 10) {
        messages.add( startMessages.get(i));
    } else {
        newMessages.add( startMessages.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What about for the else statement? That still has the set method. Why does that not cause issues?

Comment: Because it's not called until you've added 10 elements to the list.

Comment: Right but it's a different list so adding ten elements to messages means you can set newMessages?

Comment: I just changed it to add. Anyways thank you for the help. I was pretty sure I needed to change it to add without an index. So thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: You're right; I misread that. You'll need to use add() for it as well. I'll edit the code above.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is not an array. In an array, when you create it, you say how many places you need, and then you can access all of them. If you said:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

Then you can use `arr[5]` and `arr[8]` etc. Immediately.

But an `ArrayList` is not like that. It only has as many items as you *add* to it. The number that you pass to the constructor just tells it how many places you think you may need, but it's not the number of items available in the list - the initial size is 0. After you `add` an item, the size is 1, and so on. So you don't actually have to pass a number when you create the list:

```
List a = new ArrayList();  // The size is 0 but you can add items.
List b = new ArrayList(10); // The size is also 0! The 10 is just the capacity!
```

The `set` method changes an *existing* item. If you didn't add an item, then it won't work - it complains that you are trying to change an item that doesn't exist. So first, you need to use `add` to add items to the list, and then you can change them with `set`.

If you need to reverse a list, you can use `Collections.reverse(list)`. It will reverse the given list. If you want to have one straight list and one reverse list, you can do:

```
// Fill list 1 by adding to it, then:

List list2 = new ArrayList(list1);
Collections.reverse(list2);
```

This will first copy all the items from `list1` to `list2`, then reverse `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

BTW a different approach, that creates views backed by the original list.

```
int size = startMessages.size();
List<EWSMessage> messages = startMessages.subList(0, Math.min(10, size));
List<EWSMessage> newMessages =  startMessages.subList(10, Math.max(10, size));
```

I would claim this was clearer, but for the min/max checks for fewer than 10.