# Set Method of ArrayList throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

While working on `ArrayList`, I found after setting the initial size of array using the constructor with `initialCapacity`, then use `set()` will throw an exception although the array is created, but size isn't set correctly.

Using `ensureCapacity()` won't work either because it is based on the `elementData` array instead of `size`.

There are other side effects because of the static `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` with `ensureCapacity()`.

The only way to make this work is to use add() as many time as required after using the constructor.

Please check the code below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List test = new ArrayList(10);
    test.set(5, "test");
    System.out.println(test.size());
}
```

I am not sure why java is throwing this exception.

Behaviour I expected: `test.size()` should return 10 and set(5, ...) should  work.

ACTUAL: throws an Exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So is it set  method that is causing problem ?

Comment: There is no 'peculiar behaviour of `ArrayList.size()` 'here. You're not even getting there.

Comment: Ok , Will change the title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayList initial capacity and IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908037/arraylist-initial-capacity-and-indexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: I am not convinced by the answer provided there , Answer provided by ERAN i think is much simpler and self explanatory. Hence not a duplicate

Comment: This is a duplicate of the much clearer question and answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`test.set(5, "test");` is the statement that throws this exception, since your `ArrayList` is empty (`size()` would return `0` if you got to that statement), and you can't set the i'th element if it doesn't already contain a value. You must add at least 6 elements to your `ArrayList` in order for `test.set(5, "test");` to be valid.

`new ArrayList(10)` doesn't create an `ArrayList` whose size is 10. It creates an empty `ArrayList` whose initial capacity is 10.

Comment: I updated my question , it was not properly explained before please check now

Comment: @ShowStopper What's not properly explained? An ArrayList is initialized to a 0 length, regardless of its initial capacity, unless you are using a constructor that initializes the ArrayList with the elements of another Collection.

Answer (score 10):

The exception is not thrown by `test.size()` but by `test.set(5, "test");`. This is because you are setting an element at index 5 but the list is currently empty.

```
List test = new ArrayList(10);
```

does not create a list initialized with 10 `null` elements. It creates a list that has an initial capacity of 10 elements, that is the backing array has a size of 10, but the list itself is still empty.

If you want to initialize a list with 10 `null` elements, you can use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, null));
```

---

As a side note, [you should never use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1743880) like `List` but always prefer a parameterized list.

Answer (score 3):

`List test = new ArrayList(10);` creates empty list which would have capacity of 10 elements.It is not containing element at 6th position so you will not be able to set element at this position.

Answer (score 2):

`List test = new ArrayList(10);` creates **empty** `ArrayList` of raw types (`Object`) with initial capacity(*capacity of list initially, initialize internal array with length 10*) not to be confused with size(*number of elements list contains*).

To understand more first note that `ArrayList` is nothing but *manipulation* of *array* to dynamically change size of the array which we were not able to do with array directly. Ultimately, it's a ***smart*** array.

By setting *initial capacity* we are telling `ArrayList` to create size of array `10` initially (by default initial capacity is `10`).

This is what constructor is doing,

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];//creates initial array
}
```

You can increase or decrease it accordingly, say you are sure that you are going to need list with `20` elements it'll be better to set initial capacity at start. It avoids *resizing* of array if you are sure about minimum number of elements you will definitely have in list.

`test.set(5, "test");` method ***replaces*** element at specific position here it will going to replace element at index `5` with `test`. But our list is empty, it does not have any element.

Documentation of this method says,

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `index` is out of range (`index < 0`  **||**
>   `index >= size()`)

Note that size of list is `0` so index (`5`) is greater than size(`0`).

Answer (score 0):

Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

```
set
```

Parameters

index
int: index of the element to replace

element
E: element to be stored at the specified position

Returns
E
the element previously at the specified position

Throws

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your list **"Test"** is **empty** and when you are trying to

execute this statement **test.set(5, "test");** it won't be able to set that

value in the list & will show `Out of bounds exception` as it will not create 10 empty spaces.

So, you can initialize your list before:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)  // As you took ten in your code
 
{
test.add(null);   // some people also use test.add(0) instead of null , 
                 //but '0' also contains a value & considering your code please use null   
}
```